# How to create an exception to hide a language path in a url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a website that has multiple language versions. As of now the default is English.

Is there anyway I can hide the /en/ path from the url? (would like to add an exception for just en)

I would like to keep the other languages intact.

www.website.com/en/ (would like to hide en for default homepage)

www.website.com/fr/ (would like to keep the other languages as is)

Thanks!

This is for a vue.js app.

```
module.exports = [].concat.apply([],
    langs.map(lang =>
        pages.map(page => `/${lang}/${page}`)))
```

Comment: How do you set the language of the app? Are you doing this strictly by looking at the url in a component?

Comment: Why? Is English somehow more special than the other languages? Just keep `/en/` and focus on making the site great instead?

Comment: language is set with a language dropdown menu in the nav bar.

Comment: I'd also keep /en/ and when someone goes to `www.website.com` just redirect to `www.website.com/en/` except the language was set ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just check for `lang === 'en'` in your map function.

```
module.exports = [].concat.apply([],
    langs.map(lang =>
        pages.map(page => lang === 'en' ? `/${page}` : `/${lang}/${page}`)))
```

Just be careful as read in comments, if you use to read url params for defining langage or if your url scheme needs to be `'/something/otherthing'`.